# Анимация при изменении значения одного из свойств элемента

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть кнопка

```
<Button Width="100" Height="24" Header="ОК" x:Name="okButton"/>
```

Где-то в коде я меняю Width у этой кнопки.

```
okButton.Width = 200;
```

Как прописать анимацию плавного изменения размера? Т.е. как прицепить анимацию к полю Width, что бы не смотря откуда в коде я меняю его значение, срабатывала анимация?

Comment: Вам именно кнопка, или подойдёт `UserControl`?

Comment: UserControl даже лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось следующим образом: ловить изменение ширины `UserControl`'а, и запускать анимацию ширины контента.

При этом, правда, уменьшившаяся ширина `UserControl`'а «отрежет» медленно уменьшающиеся части контента, так что придётся отключить clipping вручную.

Контрол:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SlowWidthChanging.SlowResizingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlowWidthChanging">
    <local:NoClipGrid x:Name="InnerPart" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <Button>Привет, мир!</Button>
    </local:NoClipGrid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class SlowResizingControl : UserControl
{
    static DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd =
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(SlowResizingControl.WidthProperty,
                                                  typeof(SlowResizingControl));

    public SlowResizingControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (o, args) =>
        {
            dpd.AddValueChanged(this, OnWidthChanged);
            OnWidthChanged(this, null);
        };
        // обязательно отписаться, чтобы избежать утечки памяти
        Unloaded += (o, args) =>
            dpd.RemoveValueChanged(this, OnWidthChanged);
    }

    void OnWidthChanged(object self, EventArgs args)
    {
        InnerPart.BeginAnimation(
            Grid.WidthProperty,
            new DoubleAnimation(
                toValue: this.Width,
                duration: new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)),
                fillBehavior: FillBehavior.Stop));
    }
}
```

Ну и вспомогательный класс ([отсюда](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/)):

```
class NoClipGrid : Grid
{
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Можно тестировать:

```
<Window x:Class="SlowWidthChanging.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlowWidthChanging"
        Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="OuterContainer">
        <local:SlowResizingControl Height="50" Width="100" x:Name="SizeChangeTarget"/>
        <Button Width="150" Height="25" Content="Поменять ширину" Click="ChangeButtonSize"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void ChangeButtonSize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double newWidth =
            (double.IsNaN(SizeChangeTarget.Width) || SizeChangeTarget.Width == 100) ?
            200 : 100;
        SizeChangeTarget.Width = newWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно попробовать использовать триггеры событий. Например, что-нибудь наподобие такого:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation  
                    Storyboard.TargetName="okButton"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                    From="75"
                    To="200"
                    Duration="0:0:2"
                />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

Или прописать анимацию в виде "обычного" кода в каком-нибудь методе:

```
DoubleAnimation buttonAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
//Начальное и конечное значение
buttonAnimation.From = okButton.ActualWidth;
buttonAnimation.To = 200;
//Продолжительность анимации
buttonAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
//Запуск анимации
okButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, buttonAnimation);
```

Comment: Здесь используется событие самой кнопки Click; Думаю не подойдет